# combine two dataframes with new index number

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

how can i add two pandas dataframes with another one and add an index change like is show in the following example.
df1:

```
     A    B    C    D
1    1    2    3    2
2    2    2    3    1
3    2    3    2    1
```

df2:

```
     A    B    C    D
1    1    2    3    2
2    4    2    19   1
3    2    64   2    1
```

the result should be

df_sum:

```
     A    B    C    D    A_2    B_2    C_2    D_2
1    1    2    3    2    1       2       3     2
2    4    2    19   1    4       2       19    1
2    2    2    3    1    2      64       2     1
```

and then adding 4 columns with d_A = A_2-A; d_B = B_2-B; d_C = C_2-C; d_D = D_2-D:

```
     A    B    C    D    A_2    B_2    C_2    D_2   d_A   d_B   ..
1    1    2    3    2    1       2       3     2     0     0    ..
2    4    2    19   1    4       2       19    1     0     0    ..
2    2    2    3    1    2      64       2     1     0     62   ..
```

thank you,
R

Comment: Some problem with answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.add_suffix('_2')], axis=1)
#alternative solution
#df = df1.join(df2.add_suffix('_2'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  A_2  B_2  C_2  D_2
1  1  2  3  2    1    2    3    2
2  2  2  3  1    4    2   19    1
3  2  3  2  1    2   64    2    1
```

Another idea is create `MultiIndex` by parameter `keys` and then flatten it by list comprehension with `f-string`s - output is a bit different:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=('1','2'))
df.columns = [f'{j}_{i}' for i, j in df.columns]
print (df)
   A_1  B_1  C_1  D_1  A_2  B_2  C_2  D_2
1    1    2    3    2    1    2    3    2
2    2    2    3    1    4    2   19    1
3    2    3    2    1    2   64    2    1
```

Comment: but if i use df = pd.concat([df1, df2.add_suffix('_2')], axis=1) i get 6 rows and and in the A, B,C,D is a NaN in row 4 to 6.

Comment: need same index values, so use `df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.add_suffix('_2').reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1) `

Comment: i updated my question with d_A, and d_B - how would you realize this? @jezrael

Comment: i tried with delta_x = df2.sub(df1, axis='column') but then i have the same problem that i get 6 rows instead of 3, as above @jezrael

Comment: @raffa_sa You need `df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)` and `df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)` and then also `df = pd.concat([df1, df2.add_suffix('_2')], axis=1)` and should working nice `delta_x = df2.sub(df1, axis='column') `